# docker-compose error invalid type, it should be a string

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

I have the set-up for docker-compose like this

```
version: "3.2"

services:
   gitlab:
       image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
       container_name: gitlab-container
       restart: always
       environment:
           - GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
                   external_url 'https://192.46.223.235'
                   gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 10022
                   letsencrypt['enabled'] = false
                   nginx['enable'] = true
                   nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = false
                   nginx[listen_port] = 10080
                   nginx[listen_https] = false
       ports:
           - "10080:80"
           - "10022:22"

       volumes:
           - '$GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab'
           - '$GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
           - '$GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
```

So, when I run docker-compose up -d, I got the following error :

```
WARNING: The GITLAB_HOME variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.gitlab.environment contains {"GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG": "-  external_url 'https://192.46.223.235'\n-  gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 10022\n  letsencrypt['enabled'] = false\n  nginx['enable'] = true\n  nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = false\n  nginx[listen_port] = 10080\n  nginx[listen_https] = false\n"}, which is an invalid type, it should be a string
```

Help, please!

Answer (score 28):

Remove the `-` before `GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG`.

The Compose [`environment:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#environment) block supports two syntaxes:

```sh
version: '3.8'
services:
  environment_as_list:
    environment:
      - KEY=value
      - LINES=start with minus
      - COLONS=false
  environment_as_map:
    environment:
      KEY: value
      LINES: do not start with minus
      COLONS: 'true'
```

The syntax you have starts with a `-`, so it's a YAML list, but then it has `key: value` syntax, so the list item is a YAML mapping.  With the block-scalar syntax you need the mapping form, so remove the leading `-` (and fix the indentation) to make it not be a list.